# Obtaining a non-monic quadratic equation from complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

I want to apply the method in this example here:
[image]

How could you do this for the case where you end with $ 2x^2 $ in the final equation? For example, the equation:

$$ 2x^2 - 6x + 5 = 0 $$

Using the quadratic formula, we can find that its complex roots are $ 1.5 + .5i $ and $ 1.5 - .5i $.

So how could we get to the function with $ 2x^2 $ at the start, starting with those roots?

Comment: Just, multiply your derived quadratic by two? $2x^2-8x+26$

Comment: What if I want it in the form (2x - something)(x - something)?

Comment: "*Find* ***the*** *equation...*" This is misleading, since the equation is not unique. In the first example you found $y=x^2-4x+13$ but any other quadratic $y = a\left(x^2-4x+13\right)$ with $\,a \ne 0\,$ has the same roots. So for the second equation you can do the same as for the first, then multiply by the lowest common multiple at the end to eliminate the denominators.

Comment: @bgcode You know that your original quadratic looks something like $(x-a)(x-b)$? Just multiply one of the bracketed terms by $2$, either one works.

Comment: Can you clarify this: "multiply one of the bracketed terms by 2"

Comment: Here, the expression is $(x-(2-3i))(x-(2+3i))$. The two bracketed terms I am talking about are $(x-(2-3i))$ and $(x-(2+3i))$. Multiplying either one by two while keeping the other one constant works.

Comment: Thank you @Prometheus, I just did that and worked out the math and I'll post out my steps in self answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Prometheus that it's as simple as multiplying by 2 to transform equations like these that equal 0.  Here are my steps:

$$
\begin{align*}
&(x - (1.5 + 0.5i))(x - (1.5 -0.5i)) = 0 \\
&(2)(x - (1.5 + .5i))(x - (1.5 -.5i)) = 0.\\
&\quad\text{Multiplying both sides by 2,} \\
&(2x - (3 + i))(x - (1.5 -0.5i)) = 0 \\
&2x^2 - 3x + ix - 3x + 4.5 - 1.5i -ix + 1.5i + 0.5 = 0\\
&2x^2 - 6x + 5 = 0
\end{align*}
$$

I'm failing to see how this method doesn't work generally, per @dvix comment.  Here is when I try it with $ 1±0.5 $

$$
\begin{align*}
&(x - (1 + 0.5i))(x - (1 - 0.5i)) = 0 \\
&(2)(x - (1 + .5i))(x - (1 - .5i)) = 0.\\
&\quad\text{Multiplying both sides by 2,} \\
&(2x - (2 + i))(x - (1 - 0.5i)) = 0 \\
&2x^2 - 2x + ix - 2x + 2 - i -ix + i - 0.5i^2 = 0\\
&2x^2 - 4x + 2.5 = 0 \\
\end{align*}
$$

Note that this equation is a multiple of two of the monic version of the quadratic: $ (2)(x^2 - 2x + 1.25) = 2x^2 - 4x + 2.5 = 0  $

Comment: That works for those roots, but try it for $\,1 \pm 0.5 i\,$ for example. Point is you don't know in advance the value you have to multiply the equations with in order to get integer coefficients (assuming that's the unstated goal here).

Comment: ... its best to adjust coefficients after the expansion is done

Comment: @dxiv using the method above on those roots, I get $ (2x-(3+i))(x-(1.5-.5i)= 2x^2 - 4x + .25 $ which seems to have different roots..  Am I calculating incorrectly or is that what shows it doesn't work?

Comment: @bgcode Not sure what you mean there - the LHS is the same as in your answer, but the RHS is different (and wrong).

Comment: I made an error in calculation in that comment, it should have been + 2.5. I appended the math to the answer.  The math actually works out, so what's wrong with using this approach generally??

Comment: @bgcode All you achieved that way is getting $\,2x^2 - 4x + 2.5 = 0\,$ instead of $\,x^2 - 2 x + 1.25 = 0\,$ which you could get directly without the intermediate multiplication by $2$. Neither equation has integer coefficients, and you don't explain why you think the first equation is "better" than the second. And, if it's not, you don't explain why you think the intermediate multiplication by $2$ served any useful purpose.

Comment: dvix, I only did it the way I did so that I could get it in that intermediate form along the way.